# Finding coupling between crystal sites related by symmetry

Tags: quantum-spin, crystals, interactions, spin-models

Say I have a crystal and the coupling between sites is described by the following local, model Hamiltonian (a spin 1/2 system):
$$
\hat{H}_{i,j} = J \bf{S}_i\cdot\bf{S}_j+\bf{d}\cdot\left[\bf{S}_i\times\bf{S}_j\right]+\bf{S}_i\cdot\Gamma\cdot\bf{S}_j
$$
which describes the coupling of the spins on sites i and j. Here J is the isotropic term, $\bf{d}$ is the antisymetric term, and $\bf{\Gamma}$ is the symmetric, traceless term. I know all these coupling constants for a specific pair of points i,j. Now I want to generate all symmetry equivalent couplings in the crystal, but I'm having some trouble determining how to do this.

I feel, if I have a new pair of sites (i',j') and they are related to (i,j) by a rotation then since I'm coupling two spin 1/2 systems I can just rotate my reference frame by doing a bloch rotation on each spin {$\bf{S}_{i'}$ ,$\bf{S}_{j'}$}. Is this right?

The part I'm stumped on is if (i',j') are related to (i,j) by any sort of symmetry that involves a reflection. How do the coupling constant change?

Also if you have a good reference on something like this it would be greatly appreciated.

RESPONSE TO COMMENT:

I'm looking at something like BaIrO3 (https://materialsproject.org/materials/mp-542897/). I'm confused though. For a classsical spin: $S=s_x \bf{e}_x +s_y \bf{e}_y +s_z \bf{e}_z$. Since these are usual Cartesian basis elements I know they change in the usual way under rotation. Let's assume we have some symmetry $\bf{S}_i = R \bf{S}_{i'}$. Then we insert the identity $I = RR^T$ and find $$\bf{d}\cdot\bf{S}_j \times \bf{S}_i = \bf{d} \cdot  \left[R^T R\bf{S}_j \times R^T R \bf{S}_i\right]= \bf{d} \cdot  R^T \left[\bf{S}_{j'} \times \bf{S}_{i'}\right]$$
$$ = \left[\bf{R}\bf{d}\right] \cdot  \left[\bf{S}_{j'} \times \bf{S}_{i'}\right]$$.

which is what you said. When I promote my spins to operators don't things change? Maybe there's some intuition I'm lacking for this kind of stuff.

Comment: The approach I've taken in the past has just been to rotate the DM vector $\mathbf{d}_{ij}$, and use that - at least in my case - $\Gamma$ can be characterized in terms of the $\mathbf{d}_{ij}$'s. Is that applicable here?

Comment: I'm actually not sure if I can get $\bf{\Gamma}$-$\bf{d}$ correspondence. Do you just apply the usual 3 dimensional rotation operator on the DM term?

Comment: Yeah, I used a standard three-dimensional rotation matrix, and applied it on say $\mathbf{d}_{01}$ to get the other $\mathbf{d}_{ij}$ within the unit cell. Depending on the lattice, several rotation axes may be needed. Vectors for other unit cells are related by lattice translation symmetry. What system are you interested in?